# jQuery Accordion alternative (Without jQuery UI)

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have this simple fiddle with 3 lists that expand by setting each `<li>` a class of active. Is it possible I can make it slide or toggle after I set it's class to active?

Take a look at here: http://jsfiddle.net/QeyPj/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go

http://jsfiddle.net/QeyPj/7/

**Code**

```
$('.title').live('click', function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    if($(this).closest('li').hasClass('active'))
      return;

      var $this = $(this);
      $this.closest('ul').find('li.active')
      .find("div.description").slideUp(200, function(){

          $this.closest('ul').find('li.active').removeClass('active');
          $this.closest('li')
              .find("div.description").slideDown(200, function(){
                 $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
              });
       });

});
```

Comment: You know, the first time on slideDown, it shows instantly instead

Comment: Take a look at my edited answer. I have also created the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/QeyPj/10/

Comment: I was working with it... Came really close but you got me. Thanks alot again